# Get back to grub menu without reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, grub

I have two separate Linux installations on my system which I can access from grub. Is there a way to get back to the grub menu to access the other system without having to reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When grub boots the OS, grub is no more and you can't go *back* to grub from the OS as it's no longer running. Grub is not just another application, it can only be run at boot time of the computer.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's not.  Once you're booted, there's no way to transfer control to GRUB.

Instead, you can look at [User-Mode Linux](http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/) and regular virtualization (VirtualBox, Xen, etc.).